# Flow of a vector field, equivalent characterizations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, vector-fields

Given a vector field $X$ on the manifold $M$ its flow is, loosely speaking, a map $F= F(t,x)= F^t(x)$, in the variables $(t,x)\in I\times M$, such that the curve $t\mapsto F^t(x_0)$ is the unique solution of:
$$\frac{d}{dt} \Big|_{t = t_1}F^t(x_0) = X(F^{t_1}(x_0))\qquad \forall x_0,t_1\qquad (1)$$
with initial condition $F^0(x_0)= x_0.$  If this holds, then $F$ can be shown to satisfy the group law $F^{t+s} = F^t\circ F^s$ (it follows from the uniqueness theorem for  ODEs).

**Question:** assume only that $F = F^t(x)$ is some map which satisfies $F^0(x) = x$. Is the following condition $(2)$ equivalent to condition $(1)$?
$$\frac{d}{d \epsilon} \Big|_{\epsilon = 0}F^\epsilon(x) = X(x)\qquad \forall x \qquad(2)$$
In other words, is $(2)$ sufficient to show that $F$ is exactly the flow of $X$?

I want to show that $(1)$ holds, so I start writing
$$\frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=t_1}F^t(x_0) = \frac{d}{d\epsilon}\Big|_{\epsilon=0}F^{t_1+\epsilon}(x_0).$$
Now *if* the group law was true (which I don't know), then $F^{t_1+\epsilon}(x_0) = F^\epsilon(F^{t_1}(x_0))$ and the conclusion follows immediately from $(2)$.  But I don't know if the group law follows from $(2)$, basically because I can't apply directly the uniqueness theorem for ODEs.  What am I missing? Are there additional necessary conditions?

Comment: The "group law" holds but it doesn't (strictly) follow from (2). Anyways this part of the theory is local and so you can apply it to differential equations on manifolds without changes.

Comment: Of course this is not true without assuming the group law. Let $M$ be $\Bbb R^2$, $X$ some compactly supported vector field on it, and $F^t$ its flow. Now consider $\chi(t)F^t$ where $\chi$ is some bump function, 0 on $(-\varepsilon,1]$ and $1$ near 0. This is no longer the flow. You could still break your condition if $F^t$ is a diffeomorphism for all $t$. The point is you've given us only local data near 0 and no way of extrapolating to everywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow me to do a little yoga with Lie groups. You should take this as philosophy, though it can be made into rigorous mathematics.

In a Lie group $G$, a 1-parameter subgroup is a Lie group homomorphism $\gamma: \Bbb R \to G$. The following are equivalent.

(1) If you have a smooth homomorphism $\gamma: \Bbb R \to G$, it is determined by $\gamma'(0)$, by the existence and uniqueness theorem for ODEs. (Precisely, it's the unique curve with $\gamma'(t) = dL_{\gamma(t)
}(\gamma'(0))$; hwere $L_g$ is left-multiplication by $g \in G$.) You could call this the flow of the element $\gamma'(0) \in \mathfrak g$.

(2) If you have a smooth curve satisfying $\gamma'(t) = dL_{\gamma(t)
}(\gamma'(0))$, it is the flow of $\gamma'(0)$ and in particular is a 1-parameter subgroup.

But there are a great many curves $\gamma: \Bbb R \to G$ with $\gamma(0) = 1_G$ and $\gamma'(0)$ fixed that are not homomorphisms! As the sillest example, take $G = \Bbb R$; there are obviously a lot of functions on $\Bbb R$ with $f(0) = f'(0) = 0$ that are not identically zero. This condition gives us so little information on its own that we could not possibly say much about $f$ - it doesn't just give us information only local to $0$, it only tells us about what the derivative of $f$ looks like there, not any of the higher derivatives.

Now for the part that is harder to make rigorous: consider the Lie group $G = \text{Diff}_c(M)$ of compactly supported diffeomorphisms on a smooth manifold $M$. (A compactly supported diffeomorphism is one that is the identity outside a compact subset of $M$.) This is a kind of infinite-dimensional Lie group; to describe its smooth structure you need to come up with a notion of something called a "Frechet manifold". Setting up this theory is quite challenging. The Lie algebra of $G$ is the space $\mathfrak X_c(M)$ of compactly supported vector fields on $M$ (those that are zero outside a compact set). The above, applied to $G$, becomes

(1) If $F^t$ satisfies the group law and has $\frac{d}{d\varepsilon}\bigg|_{\varepsilon=0} F^\varepsilon = X$, then $F^t$ is the flow of the compactly supported vector field $X$.

(2) If $F^t$ is the flow of $X$, then it satisfies the group law.

But the observation about smooth curves to $G$ still holds: there are a great many smooth curves $\gamma: \Bbb R \to \text{Diff}_c(M)$; these are smooth maps $F^t: \Bbb R \times M \to M$ such that, for fixed $t$, $F^t$ is a compactly supported diffeomorphism of $M$. They do not have to be group homomorphisms, and hence do not have to be the flow of a vector field. Thus your (1) and (2) are quite different; as above, we just do not have information about $F^t$ away from $t=0$, and there, we only know about its derivative, not the higher derivatives in $t$.

Comment: Nice explanation and example, thank you